# Database normalisation theoretical task

Tags: database

I have theoretical problem with databases on my university, don't know how to solve this.
Task:
In which normal form are (or not) these relational schema's :

```
a)R=(U, F) where
U = {M,U,K}
F = {MU → K, K → M} 

b)R=(U,F) where 
U = {A,B,C,D} 
F = {AB → C, B → D, BC → A}

c)R=(U,F) where
U = {S, T, D, K}
F = {TS → D, SD → K}
```

will be thankful for any source or information

Comment: What is your solution thus far?

Comment: for a) i have so far F* = { M->K, K->M } U leads nowhere so I guess it's only 1st normal form because U have no key, they are just elementary

Answer (score 0):

a) seems to be in 3NF

b) has a partial dependency B->D, therefore in 1NF

c) is in 2NF